# getting .class for List <int> in java

Tags: java, generics

I have the following function

EDIT: Changed int to class Long

```
protected <T> ApiResponse<T> getApiResponse(Object obj, Class<T> clasx)
```

How can I pass `List<Long>` class as the second argument?

Can I pass `List<Long>.class` but that is not working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) means that you can only pass `List.class`.

From the linked documentation:

> When a generic type is instantiated, the compiler translates those types by a technique called type erasure — a process where the compiler removes all information related to type parameters and type arguments within a class or method. Type erasure enables Java applications that use generics to maintain binary compatibility with Java libraries and applications that were created before generics.
>
> For instance, `Box<String>` is translated to type `Box`, which is called the raw type — a raw type is a generic class or interface name without any type arguments. This means that you can't find out what type of Object a generic class is using at runtime. The following operations are not possible:

```
public class MyClass<E> {
  public static void myMethod(Object item) {
    // Compiler error
    if (item instanceof E) {
        ...
    }
    E item2 = new E();       // Compiler error
    E[] iArray = new E[10];  // Compiler error
    E obj = (E)new Object(); // Unchecked cast warning
  }
}
```

> The operations shown in bold are meaningless at runtime because the compiler removes all information about the actual type argument (represented by the type parameter `E`) at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass `int` into the `List`.
Because the `T` here should be extends from `Object`.

`Integer` is extended from `Object`, but not `int`.

Comment: There is no `Int` in Java, only `int` and `Integer` are available.

Comment: Sorry for not re-checking about this. :) I will modify the answer. But the main idea is what I said. :)